# Convert sql.GroovyRowResult with two columns to map

Tags: groovy

I have a groovy [`GroovyRowResult`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/sql/GroovyRowResult.html) (using sql.rows) with two columns. The first column has a group by in the sql, so it will always be unique.

Now I would like to convert the whole result into a map, which contains the first column value as the key and the second column value as the value. I know that I can do this with each for every single row (see below), but was wondering if there is a better aproeach. The only thing I've found is entrySet(), which did not work. Error is:

```
Message: No signature of method: 
java.util.ArrayList.entrySet() is applicable for argument types: () values: [])
```

So my each row way would be:

```
def myMap = [:]
result.each {
    myMap.put(it.colum1, it.column2)
}
```

Another alternative would be, to make the query in a way that will return me a map with the first column as the key and the second as the value (or the whole row as the value). Kind of Zend frameworks fetchAssoc() method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do:

```
def myMap = result.collectEntries {
    [ it.column1, it.column2 ]
}
```